# Excel Formula for Unique Values Not Apart of Exclusion List

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good day all,

Using Excel formulas, how do I solve for uniques within array that aren't apart of uniques from another array?

I've tried.

```
=UNIQUE(B:B&"<>header",FALSE,TRUE)

=UNIQUE(B:B,FALSE,TRUE)&"<>header"

=UNIQUE(B:B,FALSE,TRUE)-"header"

=UNIQUE(B:B,FALSE,TRUE)-{"header"}

{=UNIQUE(B:B,FALSE,TRUE)-{"header"}}

{=UNIQUE(B:B,FALSE,TRUE)}-{"header"}

{=UNIQUE(B:B,FALSE,TRUE)&"<>header"}

=UNIQUE(B:B,FALSE,TRUE)-UNIQUE("header")
```

In this example I've only excluded 1 header, however my headers will be constantly moving so it is important I can dynamically add and subtract unique items to remove from entire column.

**Edit:** Giving more information below

I've continued research and came across this article however it doesnt fit my needs.
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/extract-unique-values-but-also-exclude-names-from-another-column.1101407/

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to accomplish

[image: Image example of the spreadsheet]

Comment: So, you want to `FILTER` for when it's not in another list?

Comment: generated a quick example. in column1 i have {title1, title2, Bob, Bob, Tim, Tim, Jay, Jay, Rob, Rob} Column2 to exclude i have {0, title1, title2} I want to say all uniques in column 1 that aren't apart of column 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=FILTER(list2,COUNTIF(exclusion,list2)=0)`

Or without list 2 helper:
`=UNIQUE(FILTER(listist1,COUNTIF(exclusion,list1)=0))`

Comment: Thank you so much, with this i was able to get the following to work:  C1=UNIQUE(FILTER(OFFSET(A1,,,COUNTA(A:A)),COUNTIF(OFFSET(B1,,,COUNTA(B:B)),OFFSET(A1,,,COUNTA(A:A)))=0))

Comment: Great. Maybe use `INDEX` instead of `OFFSET` to avoid volitality (recalculating when any cell in the file is changed): `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),B1:INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(B:B)),A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)))=0))`